# spawn /usr/bin/php ENOENT error on vs code

Tags: php, symfony, visual-studio-code

Hello i am newbie on symfony . 
- trying to find definition of **AbstractController** without go on go **FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController**  by go to definition **Shift+Maj+click**  but doesnt work and i think because vs code doesn't detect symfony language and trying another way by install new extension but is still the same error

detail error :

> `spawn /usr/bin/php ENOENT error`

[image]

Comment: I don't know VSCode, but ENOENT usually means it couldn't find a file. In this case it didn't find the php executable. Do you have php installed on your computer and is it in the provided path? If not, install php/check your vscode configuration for php

Comment: Yes i install php on my machine and rely php location on path . is installed but is stay the same error ok ill install php/check now is already installed i make php --version and is give me 7.2 version of my php

Comment: It appears that the Symfony for VSCode plugin can't find php. Are there any configuration options for the plugin?

Comment: Exactly brother but is already installed on my file composer.json and i check php on my machine is work fine with xampp but i dont know exactly whats wrong .

Answer (score 14):

You have Symfony for VSCode extension installed, and its default path for php.exe is /usr/bin/php. Change it by adding this line in settings.json:

```
"symfony-vscode.phpExecutablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

and replace path to where your php.exe file is.

Comment: Add your own path, for instance I have php installed in the following path: C:\php\php.exe